# How to convert data into text while web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a website and extract the data for football players into an excel file using python.

The code works and the information is extracted but not as a text but as the HTML code. To "convert" it into text I used the `.text` modifier which results in an error message

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"
```

Could anyone of you please help. My goal is to have the name, club, minutes, etc. in an excel file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

    players = soup.find("table", 
                class_="module-statistics statistics")
    
    data=[]
    
    for player in players:
        item={}
    
        item["Name"] = player.find("td", 
                    class_="person-name").text
        item["Verein"] = player.find("td", 
                    class_="team-name")
    
        item["Minuten"] = player.find("td", 
                    class_="person_stats-playing_minutes person_stats-playing_minutes-list")
    
        item["Ballkontakte pro Minute"] = player.find("td", 
                    class_="person_stats-balls_touched_per_minute")
    
        item["Summe Ballkontakte"] = player.find("td", 
                    class_="person_stats-balls_touched person_stats-balls_touched-list")
                                    
        
        data.append(item)
    
    return data

def export_data(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel("Spieler.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data("https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik-ballkontakte/")
export_data(data)
    print("done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue here is to select more specific and exclude the row with the `<th>` because here you will not find any `<td>`:

```
players = soup.select('.module-statistics.statistics tr:has(td)')

data=[]

for player in players:
    data.append({
    'Name': player.find("td", class_="person-name").text,
    'Verein': player.find("td", class_="team-name").text,
    'Minuten': player.find("td", class_="person_stats-playing_minutes person_stats-playing_minutes-list").text,
    'Ballkontakte pro Minute': player.find("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched_per_minute").text,
    'Summe Ballkontakte': player.find("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched person_stats-balls_touched-list").text                                    
    })

return data
```

---

An alternative and best practice in scraping tables is to use `pandas.read_html()`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik-ballkontakte/')[0]
```

Based on @Timeless comment, you could add additional parameters, to get a propper result:

```
pd.read_html('https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik-ballkontakte/', decimal=',', thousands='.')[0]
```

Comment: It seems that the `"pro Minute"` column is cast to `int64` (108, 91, ..) and not `float64` (1.08, 0.91, ..).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You were a big help!

Answer (score 0):

The first `player` element was most likely empty when you were iterating the list of elements. To handle that here is a quick fix.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    players = soup.find("table", class_="module-statistics statistics")

    data = []

    for player in players:
        item = {}

        name = player.find("td", class_="person-name")
        team_name = player.find("td", class_="team-name")

        item["Name"] = name.text.strip() if name else ""
        item["Verein"] = team_name.text.strip() if team_name else ""

        # ... and so on

        data.append(item)

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data(
        "https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik-ballkontakte/"
    )
```

Comment: Although this approach shows how missing elements could be dealt with, it unfortunately does not really solve the actual problem in a sustainable way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `findNext` instead of `find`
Try Below code should work fine

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    players = soup.find("table", class_="module-statistics statistics")
    data = []
    for player in players:
        item = {}
        item["Name"] = player.find_next("td", class_="person-name").text
        item["Verein"] = player.find_next("td", class_="team-name").text
        item["Minuten"] = player.find_next("td",
                                           class_="person_stats-playing_minutes person_stats-playing_minutes-list").text
        item["Ballkontakte pro Minute"] = player.find_next("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched_per_minute").text

        item["Summe Ballkontakte"] = player.find_next("td",
                                                      class_="person_stats-balls_touched "
                                                             "person_stats-balls_touched-list").text
        data.append(item)
    return data


def export_data(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel("Spieler.xlsx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data(
        "https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik-ballkontakte/")
    export_data(data)
    print("done")
```

Comment: Please check the result, the solution duplicates the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.content` instead of `.text` for BeautifulSoup. It will be `soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")`.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Unfortunately, changing the .text to .content does not solve my problem. What modifier should I use for the items?